# Where are old posts stored in WordPress zip folder backup?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this zip folder called "wp-admin" of a website backup before I revamped the entire website from a dev url. However, I need the posts off of the old website on the new one. Is there a name for the file inside the folder that contains the posts? Or is there a general folder that I should be looking in?

Other folders inside the wp-admin folder include:
wp-admin
wp-content
wp-includes

Comment: The posts are not stored in the files. They are stored in the database table. You need to download the old database and link it to the wordpress to access the old posts.

Answer (score 0):

Wp-admin,wp-include are default wordpress folder.

All your post are stored in the database table called dbprefix_posts and dbprefix_postsmeta.

Now there is two way to import your posts to your new website>

Option 1) : Migrate your database old to new. Specially posts table and postmeta tables.

Option 2) : Login into your old admin panel find tools menu and there is sub menu of export. From the export option you can export your posts as a file. Now import that file from new admin using import option.